# Why does the font on my tkinter app look bumpy or unclear?

Tags: python, linux, debian, tkinter-text

The font on my Debian bullseye OS normally looks just fine. However, when I create an app using tkinter and place text on it, the text looks awful. I expect my tkinter apps in general to show nice font. A screenshot of how the font appears is posted at the bottom.

These are the steps I've taken to try and resolve this issue.

1. I installed: ttf-mscorefonts-installer
2. I created a fonts.conf file in the directory .config/fontconfig/fonts.conf with the code as follows:

[image: fontconfig]

While my fonts do looks much better on my OS after taking these steps, the text on my tkinter apps still look awful. For additional information, here is the code I used to my app on tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from quiz_brain import QuizBrain


THEME_COLOR = "#375362"


class QuizInterface:

    def __init__(self, quiz_brain: QuizBrain):
        self.quiz = quiz_brain
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Quizzler")
        self.window.config(padx=20, pady=20, bg=THEME_COLOR)

        self.score_label = Label(text="Score: 0", fg="white", bg=THEME_COLOR)
        self.score_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=250, bg="white")
        self.question_text = self.canvas.create_text(
            150,
            125,
            width=280,
            text="Some Question Text",
            fill=THEME_COLOR,
            font=("Courier", 20, "italic"))
        self.canvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=50)

        true_img = PhotoImage(file="images/true.png")
        self.true_button = Button(
            image=true_img,
            command=self.true_pressed,
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.true_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

        false_img = PhotoImage(file="images/false.png")
        self.false_button = Button(
            image=false_img,
            command= self.false_pressed,
            highlightthickness=0
        )
        self.false_button.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.get_next_question()

        self.window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: avoid using images of code: please write out your code or copy/paste code so that those helping you don't have to retype it. Please add what you expect your code to do, what error you are getting. [ask]

Comment: avoid using images of code: please write out your code or copy/paste code so that those helping you don't have to retype it. Please add what you expect your code to do, what error you are getting. How to Ask

Comment: the code used for configuring my font shows up on this posting as: rgb hintslight lcddefault. So I kept the image of the code so that it is displayed properly.